# Change size of <select> element using font-size?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I would like to change the font size of my select element. Everything is ok with web view but if I tried viewing it on mobile it looks larger than expected. Can anyone provide me the idea on how to fix this.Below is the screenshot of the select after changing the font-size to 1.1em
[image]

Below is the code I used for styling and the html markup

```css
select.form-control {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  height: 1.2em;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div>{{ _('Sort by') }}</div>
    <div>
      <select class="form-control" name="sort_by">
                     <option value=''>any</option>
                     <option value='1'>1</option>
                     <option value='2'>2</option>
                </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you added the `viewport` **metatag**?

Answer (score 0):

You can use media query to change the font size on smaller screens.

```
@media screen and (max-width: size){
    select.form-control {
        font-size: smallerfontsize;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The unit em [Relative to the font-size of the element (2em means 2 times the size of the current font)](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)

Take a look at DP (Device pixel) unit when developing for mobile.

Answer (score 0):

You can add media query

```
<style>
select.form-control {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  height: 1.2em;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    select.form-control {
      font-size: 10px;

    }
}
</style>
```